# Error in my bibliography whit texmaker and bibtex

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

This is my `demo.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{makeindex}

\title{Demo}
\author{Some author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
Some text with \cite{bell1998computer}.

\chapter{Second}
ToDo

\bibliography{bibliografia}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

and this is my bibliografia.bib (bibliografia.bib is the name of bibliography):

```
@book{bell1998computer,
  title={Computer Science Unplugged: Off-line activities and games for all ages},
  author={Bell, Timothy C and Witten, Ian H and Fellows, Mike},
  year={1998},
  publisher={Computer Science Unplugged}
}
```

To compile, I run the following commands, on demo.tex:
LaTeX
Bibtex
LaTeX
LaTeX

I have the following error while compiling Bibtex:

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: relazione1.aux The style file: plain.bst Database file #1: bibliografia.bib You're missing an entry type---line 1 of file bibliografia.bib : @ :

Process exited with error(s)
```

Can someone help me?
thank you all

P.s. I use TeXmaker and bibtex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you try to delete the first line of your `.bib` file and retype it to make sure there are no hidden characters? see https://www.guitex.org/home/it/forum/5-tex-e-latex/59391-errore-bibliografia-help-please?limit=6

Comment: Is your bib called `bibliografy.bib` or `bibliografia.bib`?

Comment: Seems you have two accounts. Please ask the exchange staff to [merge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them.

Comment: Now I have joined my two accounts.
My bib is called bibliografia.bib. 
Tthanks to the idea you suggested, I deleted everything, wrote the .bib file on an external editor and copied it into the .bib file and it finally worked.

Thank you all!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments